# How I can override some Javascript function from Omnifaces?

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I want to override the Javascript function called from `o:highlight` component from Omnifaces. I see that the taglib calls the function `OmniFaces.Highlight` available here:

https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/develop/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/omnifaces/highlight.unminified.js

How I can override this function to use my own implementation?

The only way I see at this time is overriding the Java class `org.omnifaces.component.script.Highlight` to call another function name.

There are another way? I don't like to override all class content because in the next time I update the Omnifaces, I need to check if the class was changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just redefine the function in JavaScript context.

```
OmniFaces.Highlight.apply = function(clientIds, styleClass, doFocus) {
    // ...
}
```

You only need to make sure this function is defined *after* `omnifaces.js` is loaded. You can ensure this by including your script with the function via a `<h:outputScript target="head">` inside `<h:body>`.

```
<h:head>
    ...
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputScript name="yourscript.js" target="head" />
    ...
</h:body>
```

Alternatively, post an [issue](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues) to OmniFaces guys and have them to implement the desired functionality you intented to change.